# dynamically change input type number decimal places

Tags: html, angularjs, input, angular-filters

I have a form and a few input type number in that form.

i need to dynamically round up the user input value to a certain configurable precision (coming from the server, present in the ngmodel, like ct.precision). My input value might be '' depending on the initial value.

I am trying to use the filter number, but I am not sure if that's how I am supposed to use it.
I have tried to use onChange, but I am not being able to set the precision with the configurable value.

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
<input
    id="quantityValue-{{ $index }}"
    class="my-quantity"
    ng-model="$ct.record[$index].newQuantity"
    type="number"
    required
    min="0"
    pattern="\d+(\.\d+)?"
    maxlength="15"
>
```

This is how my input looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-change` on both the input field and the configurable selection of precision (*whatever that might be*, I chose `<select>`). Here is a demo without validations:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.foo = function(x, n = 3) {
    $scope.x_ = Number($filter('number')(x, n));
  }
  $scope.precision = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  $scope.n = $scope.precision[0]; // default (optional)
  $scope.x = 0; // default (to remove NaN issues)
  $scope.foo($scope.x, $scope.n); // initialise precision
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="n" ng-change="foo(x,n)" ng-options="p for p in precision">
</select>
  <hr>
  <input type="number" ng-model="x" ng-change="foo(x,n)">
  <br>{{x_}}
</div>
```

(There might be some issues with rounding (*blame JavaScript*), where rounding `0.129999` gives `0.13` for precisions between 2 and 5)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but I actually need it to enforce the input to have the precision, not a display value to show it like that..

Comment: @solarapricot then rename all `x_` to `x`, it will just prevent you from typing more digits (instead of trying to round numbers up)

Comment: also `x.toFixed(n)` instead of `$filter('number')(x, n)` will work better